# Core Data Lightweight migration, unable to map the new data model

Tags: ios, ipad, core-data, core-data-migration

I am using core data in my iOS project. I am using light weight migration for migrating schema between datamodel versions.
I had version 3.5 set as current modal version for the app which is released in field. Before making new changes to the datamodel schema, I have created a new datamodel version 3.6 and added a new entity and couple of attribute updates on the new datamodel.
After completing all changes, I have created a new mapping model for 3.5 to 3.6
And I am using the following code for the light weight migration,

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
{
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:PERSISTENT_STORE_FILENAME];
NSDictionary *storeOptions = nil; 

NSError *error = nil;
_persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:storeOptions error:&error])
{

    BOOL shouldPerformLightWeightMigration;

    if (self.optionalCoreDataMigrationHandler) {
        shouldPerformLightWeightMigration = optionalCoreDataMigrationHandler();
    }

    if (shouldPerformLightWeightMigration) {
        [self performLightweightMigrationInBackgroundWithStoreURL:storeURL];
    }        
}    

return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

}

```
- (void)performLightweightMigrationInBackgroundWithStoreURL:(NSURL *)storeURL {
[self.initializerDelegate willStartMigration];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^(void){
    NSDictionary *storeOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:storeOptions error:&error]) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [self.initializerDelegate didFinishMigrationSuccessfully:NO];
        });
    } else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [self.initializerDelegate didFinishMigrationSuccessfully:YES];
        });
    }
});
```

}

When I installed the new app on top of existing app, the app became blank and did not retrieve any data and I have encountered the following error when NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification is called,

An observer of NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification illegally threw an exception. Objects saved = {....} 
and exception = Object's persistent store is not reachable from this NSManagedObjectContext's coordinator with userInfo = (null)

Same process usual works for me in another app. But for some reason it did not work here. 
In past, I had similar issue in the other app. Datamodel migration from v1 to v2 failed, so I have created a new model version v3 with v1 as source, re-did all the datamodel updates on v3 and created a new mapping model from v1 to v3. Then the lightweight migration worked.

In current scenario, I am not in a position to follow the above approach. 
Please help in resolving the current migration issue and any other best practices to avoid such problems in future, as I often make updates to the datamodel.

Comment: Have you created mapping models from v1 to v2 and then v2 then v3 and then tried executing ?